# Lock Struct(s) MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, cpu

I'm currently facing an interesting situation here with my MSQL.

I have the same SELECT query being stuck under "processlist" for more than 1500 seconds in "sending data" state.

If I run the SELECT query manually (via terminal or phpMyAdmin), the result was returned in under a second.

I did some research and found "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" and found lots of same SELECT query as the output.

```
    ---TRANSACTION 14304425756, ACTIVE 1426 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 105, locked 0
1 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 10070680, OS thread handle 0x7fb4ac04e700, query id 1360340216 192.168.1.15 root2 Sending data
SELECT ------------------- SELECT QUERY HERE ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 14304425757, sees < 14302154103
---TRANSACTION 14304424080, ACTIVE 1427 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 105, locked 0
1 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 10069995, OS thread handle 0x7fb4ac86e700, query id 1360338104 192.168.1.15 root2 Sending data
SELECT ------------------- SELECT QUERY HERE ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 14304424081, sees < 14302154103
---TRANSACTION 14304406358, ACTIVE 1436 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 105, locked 0
1 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 10070125, OS thread handle 0x7fb46fa69700, query id 1360309566 192.168.1.16 root2 Sending data
SELECT ------------------- SELECT QUERY HERE ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 14304406359, sees < 14302154103
---TRANSACTION 14304371566, ACTIVE 1452 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 105, locked 0
1 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 10070898, OS thread handle 0x7fb4ac2d8700, query id 1360253083 192.168.1.16 root2 Sending data
SELECT ------------------- SELECT QUERY HERE ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 14304371567, sees < 14302068053
---TRANSACTION 14304339535, ACTIVE 1469 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 105, locked 0
1 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 10070052, OS thread handle 0x7fb4acaf8700, query id 1360198771 192.168.1.16 root2 Sending data
SELECT ------------------- SELECT QUERY HERE ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 14304339536, sees < 14302068053
```

What does the above mean?

It seems to overload my database due to the lots of SELECT queries being stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes it means this, sometimes it means that.  Please provide the `SELECT`, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE(s)`.

Comment: The quick fix is not to allow so many connections to start; they are stumbling over each other.  The better fix may be something as simple as a new composite index.